# How to customize title page logo size from the beamer inner theme?

Tags: latex, beamer

I'm currently building a custom beamer theme and I finally found the perfect logo height `[height=0.2\textheight]` and would like to set it into my default theme (so I don't need to remember it in the future).

However, I don't know how's that possible with the `\inserttitlegraphic` command in the inner beamer theme. Here's the code:

```
% Title page
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \hfill{\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
      \centering
      % ------------------------
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\textbf{\inserttitle}\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
          \vskip0.25em%
          {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\textit{\insertsubtitle}\par}%
      \fi%
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
      \vskip0.5em\par
      % ------------------------
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
      \end{beamercolorbox}
      \vskip-1em
      % ------------------------
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
      \end{beamercolorbox}
      % ------------------------
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
      \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}

% TOC
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\leavevmode\leftskip=1.4em\rlap{\hskip-1.3em\inserttocsectionnumber.}\textbf{\inserttocsection}\par}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\leavevmode\leftskip=3.2em\rlap{\hskip-2em\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber}\inserttocsubsection\par}

% Items
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
\setbeamertemplate{block title}[]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]

% Frame
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{0.5em}\bfseries\insertframetitle\par\vskip-6pt\hrulefill\vspace{-0.1em}}
```

So far, I'm always having to add `\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{hu-logo.png}}` to my main latex document. Id like to simple reference the logo file and have this theme automatically fill in the height, *as the set logo height for this theme*

I'll appreciate the help and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the title graphic gets set with the height you choose in your theme, you could let your beamer theme do it and just offer your users the possibility to change the file name via a theme option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{beamerthemeHU.sty}
\DeclareOptionBeamer{logofile}{\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=0.2\textheight]{#1}}}
\ExecuteOptionsBeamer{logofile=example-image-duck}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer
\end{filecontents*}

\usetheme[
  logofile=example-image
]{HU}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is adding it to the tex document, right? If so, how can I define the default logo height from the theme itself (whether in inner or outer theme)?

Comment: No, this is not adding it to the tex document. I'm just using the `filecontents` environment to create a theme file, because I obviously don't have access to your's

Comment: So if I’d publish the main theme file, there I could then define the default logo height? Because in that case I can upload it to my question; in the question right now thats my inner theme file. The main theme file just has the `\useinnertheme` `\useoutertheme` and `\usecolortheme` commands.